# Joint Probability Distribution in R

Tags: r

I have marginal distribution and my x,y variables are not independent.
Is there any way I can find the joint probability distribution in R.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anyway, this might be better asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am not expert in R. but I have 50 data (like, 20,23,100,...all way to 50) on the first column and I have normalized 50 data between 0 and 1 on the second column. I dont really know how I can get their joint probability distribution or their marginal distribution in order to find their entropy and mutual information!! if you can help me how can I find joint probability and marginals when I have the data, I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

it can be done with the R- package `IPSUR`

please look into the package's documentation, especially `7.1 Joint and Marginal Probability Distributions`